# É possível recompilar um jogo em flash descompilado com o Sothink SWF Decompiler ou JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Tenho muitos jogos no formato `swf`, mas eu quero recompilar para `swf` no Adobe Flash CS6. O problema é que eles estão em ActionScript 1 e ActionScript 2, como posso recompilar?

Outro problema é que possuo muitos arquivos em `.as` que foram extraídos utilizando o Sothink SWF Decompiler, mas não sei como recompilar todos eles no Adobe Flash CS6, pois ele gera um tamanho pequeno de menos de 500kb com erros de sintaxe.

Se alguém puder responder ficarei muito grato.

Comment: É muito difícil existir uma ferramenta na web que realize esse tipo de reescrita do código de forma automática. O formato AS1/AS2 é muito diferente do AS3 e utiliza AVMs do Flash Player diferentes também. Entenda que o tamanho de um arquivo de menos de 500kb não significa muito, já gerei projetos com 16kb de programação apenas (embora não seja um jogo). Esses programas de descompilação são bons, mas limitados. Nem sempre o código gerado por eles refletem 100% o que originalmente foi escrito, em outras palavras, eles descompilam códigos apenas para "fazer funcionar".

Comment: Talvez a melhor forma de você realizar essa operação é abrir o projeto utilizando o JPEXS e reescrever o código em ActionScript 3 lembrando o que você já havia escrito anteriormente utilizando um novo `.fla` feito no Flash Professional CS6.